# how i can write a component without error in syntax certainly inside (return) ,,i have problem with a jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

how i can write a component without error in syntax certainly inside (return) ,,i have problem with a jsx

```
import React from 'react'
    import Tweet from './tweet'
    
    function App() {
    
    
    
        return ( <
            div className = "app" >
            <
            h1 > hello react < /h1> <
            Tweet / >
            <
            Tweet / >
            <
            Tweet / >
            <
            Tweet / >
            <
            /div >
        );
    }
    
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry could you specify what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: There are a ton of unnecessary spaces there.  Maybe JSX is more strict than that?  Remove all the spaces between `<` and the tag name, as well as between `/` and `>`.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Telling us that you have an error isn’t very useful, quote the exact error message. Also read the formatting instructions for questions, it looks like you’ve tried to stop `<` being treated as the start of a tag by the markdown parser by surrounding it with spaces instead of hitting the code button in the toolbar, the result is a mess that probably doesn’t reflect your actual code well at all.

Answer (score -1):

Make an element on 1 line, like this:

`<Tweet/>`

Answer (score -1):

Your return has too many spaces, try this:

```
return (<div className = "app" >
        <h1 > hello react </h1>
        <Tweet />
        <Tweet />
        <Tweet />
        <Tweet />
    </div >);
```